# How do I use multiple ListView.builder inside a ListView and to make nested scrolling using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, scroll, nested

I am facing a problem implementing a screen using the combination of both ListView and ListView.builder. The sample code is as below -

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('AppBar'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: ListView(
      controller: _mainScrollController,
      children: <Widget>[
                     ListView.builder(....) // ListView.builder #1
                     ListView.builder(....) // ListView.builder #2
                     ListView.builder(....) // ListView.builder #3
                        
     ]
   )
 )
```

It needs to scroll inner list views separately and when the user moves to the bottom or top of any list view, scrolling will be stopped for the associated inner list and control will move the main widget.

Is there any approach to implement it and to use multiple ScrollContollers inside a widget?

Comment: So, whats the problem with this approach?

Comment: Wrap listview.builders in sizedbox and give a height, Without specifying height to the children listview.builders you cannot achieve this.

Comment: @EhsanAskari , the problem is  - multiple ScrollContollers  are not being supported to handle list view specific scrolling.

Comment: @Vettiyanakan, may be he meant like ; when a inner list starts scrolling and reach to the top/bottom(content finish), then need to scroll the immediate parent list. He has multiple nested(inner) listview.builder, i believe.

Answer (score 1):

try to use [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) with multiple SliverList:

```
/// Flutter code sample for CustomScrollView

// By default, if items are inserted at the "top" of a scrolling container like
// [ListView] or [CustomScrollView], the top item and all of the items below it
// are scrolled downwards. In some applications, it's preferable to have the
// top of the list just grow upwards, without changing the scroll position.
// This example demonstrates how to do that with a [CustomScrollView] with
// two [SliverList] children, and the [CustomScrollView.center] set to the key
// of the bottom SliverList. The top one SliverList will grow upwards, and the
// bottom SliverList will grow downwards.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  List<int> top = <int>[];
  List<int> bottom = <int>[0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const Key centerKey = ValueKey<String>('bottom-sliver-list');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Press on the plus to add items above and below'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              top.add(-top.length - 1);
              bottom.add(bottom.length);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        center: centerKey,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: Colors.blue[200 + top[index] % 4 * 100],
                  height: 100 + top[index] % 4 * 20.0,
                  child: Text('Item: ${top[index]}'),
                );
              },
              childCount: top.length,
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            key: centerKey,
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: Colors.blue[200 + bottom[index] % 4 * 100],
                  height: 100 + bottom[index] % 4 * 20.0,
                  child: Text('Item: ${bottom[index]}'),
                );
              },
              childCount: bottom.length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Using, NotificationListener, the problem is resolved -itemBuilder: this.dashBoardData == null

                            ? (BuildContext context, int index) {

                                return this.getCaseList(context, new Cases());

                              }

                            : (BuildContext context, int index) {

                                return NotificationListener<

                                    OverscrollNotification>(

                                  onNotification:

Answer (score 0):

`ListView`, `shrinkWrap`, `SliverList`

[Check this for more info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUqDNnv_dh0),  [and this](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa25FblpOZDdMZm0wbUlQeVlnRVBvcGhOUXo2QXxBQ3Jtc0trU0tydGoxXzhKRkNUblM1WGR0SGZtSHBFWjBod2tSUGEybm5rbmYxSm55OTdxV1M3ZF9weGdXOXZXckhaWEdIVXNRalp5Z3ZhMXBiaHlmaUFTU0VYQl91R3NEck9jY2VOVDFPS2VzRTkzOWpyOVVrbw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gle%2F3oCRRTt).

ShrinkWrApp

```
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(ShrinkWrApp());
}

class ShrinkWrApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'ShrinkWrap vs Slivers',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("ShrinkWrap, Street Rat, I don't, Buy that!"),
        ),
        body: const ShrinkWrapSlivers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShrinkWrapSlivers extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShrinkWrapSlivers({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShrinkWrapSliversState createState() => _ShrinkWrapSliversState();
}

class _ShrinkWrapSliversState extends State<ShrinkWrapSlivers> {
  List<ListView> innerLists = [];
  final numLists = 15;
  final numberOfItemsPerList = 100;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < numLists; i++) {
      final _innerList = <ColorRow>[];
      for (int j = 0; j < numberOfItemsPerList; j++) {
        _innerList.add(const ColorRow());
      }
      innerLists.add(
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: numberOfItemsPerList,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => _innerList[index],
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: numLists,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => innerLists[index]);
  }
}

@immutable
class ColorRow extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorRow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => ColorRowState();
}

class ColorRowState extends State<ColorRow> {
  Color? color;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    color = randomColor();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Building ColorRowState');
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          colors: [
            randomColor(),
            randomColor(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Column(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Text('I\'m a widget!',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Color randomColor() =>
    Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);
```

SliversApp

```
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(SliversApp());
}

class SliversApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'ShrinkWrap vs Slivers',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Revenge of the Slivers"),
        ),
        body: const ShrinkWrapSlivers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShrinkWrapSlivers extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShrinkWrapSlivers({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShrinkWrapSliversState createState() => _ShrinkWrapSliversState();
}

class _ShrinkWrapSliversState extends State<ShrinkWrapSlivers> {
  List<SliverList> innerLists = [];
  final numLists = 15;
  final numberOfItemsPerList = 100;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < numLists; i++) {
      final _innerList = <ColorRow>[];
      for (int j = 0; j < numberOfItemsPerList; j++) {
        _innerList.add(const ColorRow());
      }
      innerLists.add(
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) => _innerList[index],
            childCount: numberOfItemsPerList,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(slivers: innerLists);
  }
}

@immutable
class ColorRow extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorRow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => ColorRowState();
}

class ColorRowState extends State<ColorRow> {
  Color? color;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    color = randomColor();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Building ColorRowState');
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          colors: [
            randomColor(),
            randomColor(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Column(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Text('I\'m a widget!',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Color randomColor() =>
    Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);
```